# Secure Playback: Crash observed in MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-mediacodec, stagefright

I am working on enabling secure playback on `Lollipop`. I am using [`ExoPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) to validate the usecase. I am able to create a secure `OMX` video decoder component(H264.secure).

However, after the creation, I am facing a crash in `MediaCodec` as shown below

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xf0300000
eax f0300000  ebx ec1da038  ecx 00000005  edx 00000002
esi ec3ca200  edi f325b148
xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 000000bf  xss 0000002b
eip ec0e1655  ebp e05ffb28  esp e05ffa90  flags 00210202  

#00 pc 000b5655  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onQueueInputBuffer(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+1061)
#01 pc 000b7b16  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+1894)
#02 pc 0000e039  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooperRoster::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+345)
#03 pc 0000d3d0  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+256)
#04 pc 0000d4ed  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::LooperThread::threadLoop()+29)
#05 pc 000169de  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+398)
#06 pc 0006fe92  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
#07 pc 000160fa  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
```

After some analysis i found that the crash occurs at function `ACodec::allocateBuffersOnPort`

I am a newbie on android. Any pointers to debug this would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, the issue is specific to a **case when `kFlagIsSecure` is set** and the creation of `OMX` buffer in a different process as compared to `MediaCodec`, which leads to a segmentation fault when accessed in `MediaCodec`.  Please refer below for the detailed background about this issue.

To overcome this issue, I would recommend the following changes in `ACodec`

```
size_t totalSize = def.nBufferCountActual * def.nBufferSize;
mDealer[portIndex] = new MemoryDealer(totalSize, "ACodec");

/* Check if the component resides in same pid as ACodec */
bool isLocalComponent = mOMX->livesLocally(mNode, getpid()); // New Code

for (OMX_U32 i = 0; i < def.nBufferCountActual; ++i) {
   sp<IMemory> mem = mDealer[portIndex]->allocate(def.nBufferSize);
   ...
   ...
```

and modify the check for allocation as below

```
-- if ((portIndex == kPortIndexInput && (mFlags & kFlagIsSecure))
--      || mUseMetadataOnEncoderOutput) {

// Modified check
++if (isLocalComponent && ((portIndex == kPortIndexInput && (mFlags & kFlagIsSecure))
++      || mUseMetadataOnEncoderOutput)) {
```

**P.S:** I would recommend you to check with Google about this solution.

**Background:**

`ExoPlayer` creates a video decoder as a `MediaCodec` component.  When a new `MediaCodec` component is created, the [corresponding object in `JNI` is created](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp#1473). Please [**note that there is no interaction**  with `MediaPlayerService`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp#110) in this process.

`MediaCodec` internally creates an `ACodec` which interacts with the `OMX` core and subsequently `OMX` component.

`ACodec` is created in the same context as `MediaCodec`. When [`OMXClient::connect`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#4504) is invoked, the `OMX` handle is created in the `MediaPlayer` service's context. Hence, the process id of `OMX` component and `ACodec` would be different.

For secure input buffers, [there is a special handling in `ACodec::allocateBuffersOnPorts`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#565). Here, the buffer pointer returned from allocateBuffer is wrapped as `ABuffer` and queued for consumption.  In my view, there is a potential issue in the current implementation as below.

`ACodec::allocateBufferOnPort` calls `mOMX->allocateBuffer`. `mOMX` is of type `IOMX` i.e. there is a binder interaction involved. Please do note this variable `&buffer_data` which will translate to `ptr` in `ACodec::allocateBufferOnPorts` layer as this is critical for the following part.

In `OMXNodeInstance` which actually runs in `MediaPlayerService`'s context, a traditional `OMX_AllocateBuffer` is called. In `OMXNodeInstance::allocateBuffer`, after the allocation `*buffer_data` is initialized with `header->pBuffer` which is basically a local pointer allocated by the `OMX` component potentially through a simple `malloc` call.

When the control returns, the same pointer is written into the binder interface [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp#861) and subsequently read back [here](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp#409). So, when the control comes out `mOMX->allocateBuffer`, the value of `ptr` is equivalent to `header->pBuffer` allocated by `OMX` component, but both of which are in 2 different processes.

Hence, when `ACodec` creates the `ABuffer` based on this `ptr` which is then accessed in `MediaCodec`, there will be an access violation as the address was created in a different process' context as compared to `MediaCodec`'s process id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ganesh. With your proposed work around the playback is fine